# Identify outliers in 3D space

Tags: math, statistics

I want to plot the trajectory of a rocket using X, Y, and Z coordinates. I think the first step is to identify and eliminate from the data set any outliers. How should I approach this issue (i.e., identifying outliers)?

I'm not a math/stats person, so I've read through Stack Overflow looking for options, but haven't found any that seem appropriate.

I have no code to show.

Comment: This question should rather go to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Start by defining what the characteristics of an outlier are.  Perhaps an outlier is one whose distance or direction from a previous position suggest the rocket has accelerated at an impossible rate, or leapt an impossible distance.  But we can't tell you what those characteristics are and identifying them isn't really a programming problem at all.  It is *rocket science* !

Comment: Eliminating outliers is a risky business. Unless there is a good rationale for doing so (e.g. a model of data collection which implies that a certain percentage of observations are spurious) you risk eliminating *data* from your calculations in such a way that you get a false idea of the variance of your data. In any event, this is definitely off-topic here but might be a good fit for [statistics.se] (but make sure to read their posting guidelines).

Comment: Thank you all for your insights. I will redirect my question to either Stack Exchange or Cross Validated.